# Do I have to link the files with -lgcc?

Tags: c, gcc, osdev

If you've ever linked a kernel with gcc you may know the parameter -lgcc.
Is this parameter important ? What does it do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do some driver/kernel dev, you may use the `-nostdlib` to remove your module from the bloated stdlib. However, you also remove all the internal hacks GCC has in order to have a consistent behaviour on a whole range of hardware.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Link-Options.html

> -nostdlib
>
> Do not use the standard system startup files or libraries when linking. No startup files and only the libraries you specify will be
>   passed to the linker, options specifying linkage of the system
>   libraries, such as -static-libgcc or -shared-libgcc, will be ignored.
>   The compiler may generate calls to memcmp, memset, memcpy and memmove.
>   These entries are usually resolved by entries in libc. These entry
>   points should be supplied through some other mechanism when this
>   option is specified.
>
> One of the standard libraries bypassed by -nostdlib and -nodefaultlibs is libgcc.a, a library of internal subroutines that GCC uses to overcome shortcomings of particular machines, or special needs
>   for some languages. (See Interfacing to GCC Output, for more
>   discussion of libgcc.a.) In most cases, you need libgcc.a even when
>   you want to avoid other standard libraries. In other words, when you
>   specify -nostdlib or -nodefaultlibs you should usually specify -lgcc
>   as well. This ensures that you have no unresolved references to
>   internal GCC library subroutines. (For example, `__main', used to
>   ensure C++ constructors will be called; see collect2.)

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gccint/Interface.html#Interface

> 3 Interfacing to GCC Output
>
> GCC is normally configured to use the same function calling convention
>   normally in use on the target system. This is done with the
>   machine-description macros described (see Target Macros).
>
> However, returning of structure and union values is done differently
>   on some target machines. As a result, functions compiled with PCC
>   returning such types cannot be called from code compiled with GCC, and
>   vice versa. This does not cause trouble often because few Unix library
>   routines return structures or unions.
>
> GCC code returns structures and unions that are 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes
>   long in the same registers used for int or double return values. (GCC
>   typically allocates variables of such types in registers also.)
>   Structures and unions of other sizes are returned by storing them into
>   an address passed by the caller (usually in a register). The target
>   hook TARGET_STRUCT_VALUE_RTX tells GCC where to pass this address.
>
> By contrast, PCC on most target machines returns structures and unions
>   of any size by copying the data into an area of static storage, and
>   then returning the address of that storage as if it were a pointer
>   value. The caller must copy the data from that memory area to the
>   place where the value is wanted. This is slower than the method used
>   by GCC, and fails to be reentrant.
>
> On some target machines, such as RISC machines and the 80386, the
>   standard system convention is to pass to the subroutine the address of
>   where to return the value. On these machines, GCC has been configured
>   to be compatible with the standard compiler, when this method is used.
>   It may not be compatible for structures of 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes.
>
> GCC uses the system's standard convention for passing arguments. On
>   some machines, the first few arguments are passed in registers; in
>   others, all are passed on the stack. It would be possible to use
>   registers for argument passing on any machine, and this would probably
>   result in a significant speedup. But the result would be complete
>   incompatibility with code that follows the standard convention. So
>   this change is practical only if you are switching to GCC as the sole
>   C compiler for the system. We may implement register argument passing
>   on certain machines once we have a complete GNU system so that we can
>   compile the libraries with GCC.
>
> On some machines (particularly the SPARC), certain types of arguments
>   are passed “by invisible reference”. This means that the value is
>   stored in memory, and the address of the memory location is passed to
>   the subroutine.
>
> If you use longjmp, beware of automatic variables. ISO C says that
>   automatic variables that are not declared volatile have undefined
>   values after a longjmp. And this is all GCC promises to do, because it
>   is very difficult to restore register variables correctly, and one of
>   GCC's features is that it can put variables in registers without your
>   asking it to.